# Galois groups of special polynomials

Tags: polynomials, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

This question is motivated by long experiments with GAP.

Call a monic polynomial with integer coefficients special in case it is irreducible and has only coefficients $-1$, $0$ or $1$. Let $n \geq 5$.

> Question 1: In case $n=p$ is a prime number, is it true that any special polynomial of degree $n$ is not solvable by radicals, or equivalently has non-solvable Galois group?

This was true for all primes $\leq 17$, in fact all such polynomials has Galois group $S_n$ (and there are over 100000 such polynomials for primes less than or equal 13), which motives the stronger question:

> Question 1': In case $n=p$ is a prime number, is it true that any special polynomial of degree $n$ has Galois group $S_{n}$?

This is also true  for $p=2,3$ by the way.